# Any changes made to an object, changes also the current object

Tags: java, object, reference, copy

Sorry, the title is not very understandable, but my English is not helping. I am a new programmer in java, and despite having read how parameters work, I do not really understand what is happening.

```
sudokuBoard alter = new sudokuBoard();
this.createRandomSudokuBoard();
alter.setBoardFromArray(this.getBoard().clone());

(...) 

for(int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
    alter.clearCell(positionListonX[i], positionListonY[i]); <<<<<<<<<<<<< Here
    if(alter.numberOfSolutions(2) < 2) {
        this.clearCell(positionListonX[i], positionListonY[i]);
        alter.setBoardFromArray(this.getBoard().clone());
    } else {
        alter.setBoardFromArray(this.getBoard().clone());
    }
}
```

What happens is that in the indicated line, calling the method `clearCell` of the object `alter` is also modifying the current object (this). In a last desperate attempt, I tried to resolve it with the `clone()` method (as you can see), but it did not work.

What's going on? What am I missing? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't implemented `clone()` in `SudokuBoard`, then you're probably getting the default `clone()` defined on `Object`, which doesn't perform a deep copy of the object.  See [Deep Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy) for an explanation.  If you actually want a completely separate instance of your board in `alter`, you will need to do something like this:

```
class SudokuBoard
{
    public void setBoard( SudokuBoard other )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 81; i++ )
        {
            this.positionListonX[i] = other.positionListonX[i];
            this.positionListonY[i] = other.positionListonY[i];
        }
        // Copy any other properties
    }
}
```

Note that if the values in your `positionListonX` and `positionListonY` arrays are not primitive types, you'll also need deep copies of those.  This is effectively a copy constructor, but I didn't give it that signature (`public SudokuBoard( SudokuBoard other)`) because I don't know the rest of the internals of SudokuBoard.

It would help to see more of the method signatures defined in your SudokuBoard class, so we know what methods are available and can understand what they do.

**Edit**

```
class SudokuBoard
{
    public void setBoardFromArray( int[][] otherBoard )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < otherBoard.length; i++ )
        {
            // Clone the arrays that actually have the data
            this.board[i] = otherBoard[i].clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I understand it better, thank you very much. The code of the class is here http://pastebin.com/fjCP7DQL It is not completed, its undocumented, and not finished.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to keep a copy and only make changes to this.board when you know the change is good.  You'll want to update setBoardFromArray to do the element-by-element copy instead of just assigning the array.  I believe your `clone` call didn't work because you were cloning a reference to another array, not the data itself.  See my edit for a `setBoardToArray` that I think will do what you want.